# SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 1:33 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'sum'

Tags: hive, hql, data-analysis

My command was this in hive shell:

```
select name_of_state, max(total_confirmed_cases/sum(total_confirmed_cases)) from total_india_case;
```

I got this error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 1:33 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'sum'
```

Plzzz help

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because you are not using group by clause. You can't use aggregate functions like this.

I am not sure what are you trying to achieve, but assuming that you want to fetch the state name having maximum ration of total_confirmed_cases to entire India.

```
With total_sum as (
Select sum(total_confirmed_cases) total from total_india_case)

Select name_of_state, max(total_confirmed_cases)/total from total_india_case
left outer join total_sum on 1=1
group by name_of_state, total limit;
```